# env['warden'] not working with Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im following this guide to create Chatting feature with a use of Websockets.
https://www.sitepoint.com/rails-and-actioncable-adding-advanced-features/

Im stuck with a problem that `env['warden'].user` is retuning nothing even when Im loggined to the app with standard Devise form.

And if I use another method (which is commented now) - it return wrong user

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected

    def find_verified_user # this checks whether a user is authenticated with devise
      verified_user = env['warden'].user

      if verified_user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end

    # def find_verified_user
    #     user_id = request.headers['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']
    #     if verified_user = User.find_by(user_id)
    #        verified_user
    #     else
    #        reject_unauthorized_connection
    #     end
    # end

  end
end
```

Logs says

```
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-06 17:40:17 +0300
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
An unauthorized connection attempt was rejected
Failed to upgrade to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found solution on this article 
https://rubytutorial.io/actioncable-devise-authentication/

Im not sure how it works, but it does the deal. How it would help for people with similar problem.

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
      logger.add_tags 'ActionCable', current_user.email
    end

    protected
    def find_verified_user
      verified_user = User.find_by(id: cookies.signed['user.id'])
      if verified_user && cookies.signed['user.expires_at'] > Time.now
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end

  end
end
```

And I also created /config/initializers/warden_hooks.rb file

```
Warden::Manager.after_set_user do |user,auth,opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = user.id
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = 60.minutes.from_now
end

Warden::Manager.before_logout do |user, auth, opts|
  scope = opts[:scope]
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.id"] = nil
  auth.cookies.signed["#{scope}.expires_at"] = nil
end
```

Comment: The link to the ref is dead.

Comment: I used this answer but I had to plug in Okomikeruko's piece of code as well to make things work.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem, but it turned out my issue was because I had two Devise models: `User` and `Customer`, since User was used for admin stuff, Customer was set to Warden's `default_scope`. So to access the `user` scope, I had to do the following

```
env['warden'].user(:user)
```

The symbol at the end defines the scope to use.

Here's where I found information on Warden's Scoped Users: https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden/wiki/Scopes#scoped-user-access

Comment: That's the way it works in combination with active admins default admin_user and a "normal" user model.

Answer (score 1):

Using Devise for authentication, I just ran into the same problem and the accepted answer didn't help me. My mistake was in my routes.rb file.
I placed: `mount ActionCable.server, at: '/cable'`
inside the `authenticate :user do` block. Moving it into the: `Rails.application.routes.draw do` block resolved the issue for me.